# 9.2: More than one Product Template from one Commerce Catalog

Tags: content-editor, commerce-catalog

So, in our Bizfx we defined a catalog *Catalog* containing two categories, *Category_1* and *Category_2*.

In Content Editor the catalog displays the items from both categories with *CommerceProduct* template. When we change the Product template field to of the *Catalog* to our custom template *Template_A*, all the items are assigned the *Template_A*

Now, what we need is to set Product template on category level, not catalog level. In other words, we want Content Editor to show items under *Category_1* as *Template_A*, and items under *Category_2* as *Template_B*